# Object or Struct result returned by COM server in C#

Tags: c#, object, com, struct

I want to make a `C#` web parser module for a legacy program written in `Delphi 6` and decided to use `COM` for that. C# module should be a COM server in a class library. With base types everything is clear, but how to decorate COM classes if the parser returns an object with a struct inside? Should the returned object and struct be declared somehow like a COM classes too?

Here is a bit of code:

```
public struct SubitemParseResult
{
   public string Field1;
   public string Field2;
   public string Field3;
}

//Should it be decorated with InterfaceType and Guid too?
public class ItemParseResult
{
   public string Field1;
   public int Field2;
   public datetime Field3;
   public SubitemParseResult SubitemField;
}

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual), Guid("BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB")]
public interface IItemParser
{
    .................
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), Guid("AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA")]
public class ItemParser : IItemParser
{
    .....
    public ItemParseResult GetAndParse(string code)
    {
       .....
    }
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's required to allow the client code to access the members.  Change the fields into properties.

Using a struct in COM is iffy since it requires a type library to make IRecordInfo work, not sure how much help you'll get from Delphi.  It is otherwise easily replaced with an interface with 3 properties.

Comment: So, you suggest to make a class out of struct and turn fields into properties everywhere, right?

Comment: COM only supports methods, a field can't work.  A property is just syntax sugar for a get and a set method.  Returning a struct from a method can work but you need IRecordInfo to access it.  Unpleasant if the language runtime doesn't help.